# Connect GPON to my home fiber network

Tags: networking, fiber

Next year, FTH will be available to me. If I understand correctly, a GPON is used to convert the signal to ethernet, which can go to my router.

However, I'm in the process of replacing my CAT6 wiring to OM4 optical cabling, and now I am confused on how I need to connect the FTH to my network. I don't want to convert to ethernet anymore. Are there GPON's that can convert the signal from the ONT to a "normal" multimode LC connection instead of an ethernet connection?

Comment: What do the acronyms you've used mean?

Comment: Also, what part of your network is CAT6 that you're trying to replace?

Answer (score 0):

> If I understand correctly, a GPON is used to convert the signal to ethernet, which can go to my router.

GPON *is* the signal, or rather it is the *optical network* that delivers the signal to you.

The *converter* for GPON is called either an "ONT" (optical network terminal) or I think an "ONU"? depending on manufacturer.

Also, an ONT does slightly more than just convert the raw signal; it has to actually coordinate with the OLT at the base to avoid colliding with all the other ONTs (i.e. other nearby customers) connected to the same PON, as well as to authenticate you (and get the decryption keys).

(This is in contrast to Ethernet media converters, which do indeed just put the same Ethernet signal on a different medium. Some ISPs actually use Ethernet as their FTTH protocol, but GPON is more common.)

> Are there GPON's that can convert the signal from the ONT to a "normal" multimode LC connection instead of an ethernet connection?

A "normal" multimode LC connection **would still be Ethernet.** There are a few other networks that run over fiber, but for building a general-purpose home LAN that uses IP networking, you'll almost certainly be using not Infiniband and not Fibre Channel, but Ethernet over that OM4.

GPON, meanwhile, is not Ethernet – due to being a passive network with many customers sharing the same fiber it has its own specific signalling that really *needs* an ONT to be present.

Also, many GPON-using ISPs will insist that you use *their* ONT specifically (partly because such devices aren't entirely compatible across manufacturers), so likely you won't have much of a choice but to use the ONT that you were issued, which will have only copper Ethernet ports most of the time.

So the easiest option is to plug your ONT into an RJ45 port of an Ethernet switch (or media converter), with your OM4 fiber being connected to an SFP port of the same Ethernet switch (or media converter).

Comment: Okay, I might have some terminology mixed up. Still, converting the FTH signal to CAT5/6 first, and then convert it to my multimode LC infrastructure. This will introduce extra latency I want to avoid. I could place a switch near the fiber terminal which accepts SFP+ modules, and put a GPN module and LC module in there. But I guess I need to check with my manufacturer which modules are compatible.

Comment: How much extra latency do you expect it will introduce? (And if that's the primary concern, wouldn't you just connect the ONT directly to the router over CAT6?)

Comment: Because I intend to re-wire my house and remove all in-wall CAT6 with OM4 cable, as I explained in my post. And the fiber terminal will be located in a different room than my router. So this means I need to keep one CAT6 just for the fiber terminal, which I don't want to do. I'm aware I still need to use some form of CAT cable to connect my devices, but the in-wall cabling will be replaced by optic.

IMO, "fiber -> fiber" is more efficient than "fiber -> ethernet -> fiber"